# Couchbase : cbimport only importing last row

Tags: couchbase

**Task** : Importing a json to a local couchbase DB. This is from the tutorial CB110 on learn.couchbase.com.

**Issue** : Only the last row, from thousands of other json rows, gets imported.

**Command** :
$cbimport json -c couchbase://127.0.0.1 -u Administrator -p abcd -b couchmusic2 -f lines -d file://C:/Users/Deep_Kulshreshtha/Downloads/CB110-Data/couchmusic2-userprofiles.json -t 1 -g %type%::%username%

**Result** : 
Json `file://C:/Users/Deep_Kulshreshtha/Downloads/CB110-Data/couchmusic2-userprofiles.json` imported to `http://127.0.0.1:8091` successfully

**Couchbase Admin Screen** :

[image]

You can see only a single row is imported. This is the last row from the import document, which contains 50,000 records.

Any pointers or help is much appreciated ! Thanks.

Deep

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution.

Windows users : Please use ^ as escape character in your key generation parameters.

Following worked for me:
-g %type%::​^​%username​^​%

Thanks.